# How to use the Multi-variate Anomaly Detection Cognitive Service by Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-anomaly-detection, azure-anomaly-detector, azure-ai

In the latest version of the Anomaly Detection Service by Azure which supports the Multi-variate Cognitive Service, we need to train a model and then consume it.

The [quickstart documentation for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/anomaly-detector/quickstarts/client-libraries-multivariate?pivots=programming-language-python) mentions a few libraries which are not getting imported:

```
from azure.ai.anomalydetector.models import DetectionRequest, ModelInfo
```

Both these libraries are throwing import errors.
How can we use the Multivariate Anomaly Detection Service using the Python SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was with version `azure-ai-anomalydetector==3.0.0b2`. With version `azure-ai-anomalydetector==3.0.0b3`, this has been addressed.

The problem is because of the change of the response format recently. To solve that issue, you can change the line with error to

```
model_status = self.ad_client.get_multivariate_model(trained_model_id).model_info.status
```

Comment: Side note, we're working to release the stable version of this as we speak, it should land before this summer. Feel free to open any questions on this SDK on our repo as well:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues